# Heroku error: Magick::ImageMagickError - not authorized

Tags: ruby, heroku, imagemagick, sinatra

I am getting the following error when deploying and running on heroku and cant find an answer. From googling it looks like i need to update a policy.xml file but i cant see how to do this with heroku.

2016-11-18T02:21:57.849452+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-11-18 02:21:57 - Magick::ImageMagickError - not authorized `//bec2df9eb90bb6604cfc-660d71a7a33bc04488a7427f5fddcedf.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/uploads/product_image/photo/570b79cdec604672a70001cc/xlarge_silk_fred_08_201627078_1.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454:

Any help would be great thanks. Im running sinatra and ruby.

Ive also tried [this](https://gist.github.com/yanowitz/8329d8b27d8294ca7027f504326fd629) without any luck, same error.

Comment: Are you also reading from_blob?